# From a list of couples of rows to a flat list of rows

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, cartesian-product

I'd like to find couples of items which have a `price` difference of less than 5$. It works with:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE mytable (id integer, price integer, name text)')
NAMES = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C', 'Item D', 'Item E', 'Item F']
PRICES = [100, 101, 102, 189, 190, 229]
for i in range(len(NAMES)):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (i, PRICES[i], NAMES[i]))

c.execute('SELECT mt1.*, mt2.* FROM mytable mt1, mytable mt2 WHERE ABS(mt1.price - mt2.price) < 5 AND mt1.id < mt2.id')

for e in c.fetchall(): print e
```

> (0, 100, u'Item A', 1, 101, u'Item B')
>   (0, 100, u'Item A', 2, 102, u'Item C')
>   (1, 101, u'Item B', 2, 102, u'Item C')
>   (3, 189, u'Item D', 4, 190, u'Item E')

**How to get a flat list instead of a list of couples?** i.e. :

```
(0, 100, u'Item A')      # 1st item of couple #1  
(1, 101, u'Item B')      # 2nd item of couple #1  
(0, 100, u'Item A')      # 1st item of couple #2  
(2, 102, u'Item C')      # 2nd item of couple #2  
(1, 101, u'Item B')      # 1st item of couple #3  
(2, 102, u'Item C')      # 2nd item of couple #3  
(3, 189, u'Item D')      # 1st item of couple #4  
(4, 190, u'Item E')      # 2nd item of couple #4
```

Comment: By flat list, would you mean you want your data to be: `[0, 100, u'Item A']`? That could be done by just changing `print e` to `print list(e)`

Comment: `SELECT mt1.* FROM mytable mt1, mytable mt2 WHERE ABS(mt1.price - mt2.price) < 5 AND mt1.id < mt2.id')
UNION 
SELECT mt2.* FROM mytable mt1, mytable mt2 WHERE ABS(mt1.price - mt2.price) < 5 AND mt1.id < mt2.id')`

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I was under the impression you wanted to just change a tuple (couple) to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select mt.*
from mytable mt
where exists (select 1 from mytable mt2 where abs(mt.price - mt2.price) < 5 and mt.id <> mt2.id);
```

This does not arrange them in any particular order, though.

If you do want them in order, then perhaps unpivoting is the best option:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN mt1.id ELSE mt2.id END) as id,
       (CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN mt1.price ELSE mt2.price END) as price,
       (CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN mt1.name ELSE mt2.name END) as name
 FROM mytable mt1 JOIN
     mytable mt2 
     ON ABS(mt1.price - mt2.price) < 5 AND mt1.id < mt2.id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2) n
ORDER BY mt1.id, mt2.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the second version I get `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: n`. In the first version, I noticed we don't get duplicates (because it's a set-theory "union", is that right?), is there a way to get duplicates with your first solution? (like in the end of my question)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of globing all columns try specifying your column names:

```
SELECT mt1.id, mt1.price, mt1.name,
mt2.id, mt2.price, mt2.name,
FROM mytable mt1, mytable mt2
WHERE ABS(mt1.price - mt2.price) < 5
AND mt1.id < mt2.id
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't provide a flat list (like in the end of question), but a list of coupled rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table to know which table mt1 or mt2 to get the values. This will also similar to your original query.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN tbl.col='mt1' THEN mt1.id ELSE mt2.id END) as id,
    (CASE WHEN tbl.col='mt1' THEN mt1.price ELSE mt2.price END) as price,
    (CASE WHEN tbl.col='mt1' THEN mt1.name ELSE mt2.name END) as name
 FROM mytable mt1, mytable mt2,
(SELECT 'mt1' as col 
 UNION SELECT 'mt2' ) tbl
WHERE ABS(mt1.price-mt2.price) < 5 
AND mt1.id < mt2.id
ORDER BY mt1.id, mt2.id;
```